# Show Hide Root Node based on child Node in Kendo TreeView

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-treeview

I need to show/hide root node and child node using kendoTreeView without checkboxes.

Scenarios are:

1)when i click on root node then all child node should get hide.
2)when i click on single child Node then that single node get hide.
3)when i click on all the child node then the root should get hide.
4)when i click again to show child node then root node should be shown.

I am able to achieve 1 and 2 using below code but 3 and 4 step is not working.

Please see below code:

```
 select: function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var item = $(e.node);
                var treeviewData = treeview.data("kendoTreeView");
                var node = treeviewData.dataItem(e.node);
                var rootNode = treeviewData.dataItem(treeviewData.parent(e.node));
                node.isSelected = !node.isSelected;
                if(node && node.items && node.items.length > 0){
                    var childern = $(item).find('.k-in');
                    var childrenDataItem;
                    if(childern){
                         for (var i = 0; i < childern.length; i++) {
                             childrenDataItem =  treeviewData.dataItem(childern);
                             childrenDataItem.isSelected = node.isSelected;
                            $this._changeLegendState(childern[i],rootNode,node.isSelected);
                         }
                    }

                }else{
                        $this._changeLegendState(item,rootNode,node.isSelected);
                }
```

Now, On the basis of this i am caling (_chanegLegendState) Method in which i am adding classes for show/hide.

```
_changeLegendState : function(node,rootNode,isSelected){
        if(isSelected){
            if($(node).hasClass("chartlegend-selected")){
                $(node).removeClass("chartlegend-selected");
                $(node).addClass("chartlegend-unselected");

            }else if($(node).hasClass("chartlegend-unselected")){
                $(node).removeClass("chartlegend-unselected");
                $(node).addClass("chartlegend-selected");
            }else{
                $(node).addClass("chartlegend-selected");
            }
        }
        }
```

Please suggest me what i am missing on how to achieve the 3 and 4 step or if there is any other easier way of achieving the above 4 steps.